# git branches are showing the same contents

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I am new to git and am learning to branch and merge.

When I perform the following operation:

> git checkout -b test

a new branch is created, I am switched to that branch.
When I:

> vim testfile

and enter some text and save, testfile is created as expected.
However when I then change to another branch via the following command:

> git checkout master

or

> git checkout unrelatedBranch

I find that the testfile also exists in these other branches with the same contents.

This behavior is inconsistent with my understanding of how branching works. Several internet resources have indicated that the commands I used here were what was needed.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong or why this is desired behavior?

Comment: Did you commit the testfile before switching to another branch? If not, it's not in any of the branches but *is* in your working directory.

Comment: You did not commit the new file `testfile` to local repo. So, when you checkout to `master` or `unrelatedBranch`, the uncommitted changes are also checked out to them. Hence you are seeing `testfile` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the `testfile` is not under version control.

Try running `git status` first to see if it lists `testfile` under `Untracked files`.

Example:

```
git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   testfile
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

If you see `testfile` listed under `untracked files` like in the above example, you need to add it to version control using the `git add` command.

```
git add testfile
```

Finally, do not forget to commit the change using `git commit`

Answer (score 3):

`testfile` is untracked, and your change isn't committed.

As a result, `testfile` *isn't* on all branches. It's on *no* branches. Git doesn't know it's even there, so it can't clean it out of the working directory when it switches branches. This is helpful (if unexpected) behavior, because you'd hate to have git messing with untracked files.

Do:

```
git add testfile
git commit -m "Adding testfile to branch test"
git checkout master
```

and you'll see testfile go away.

Comment: What would you do if you are not finish with the testfile and therefore not ready to commit, but have to work on the other branch? Stashing?

Answer (score 2):

It might be because the file is not being tracked.

Try doing: `git add testfile` to add it to the new branch.