# Git File created in branch is also visible in master

Tags: git, github

New to Git and the command-line, and i'm trying to figure my way around.

I've successfully created a linked my local repository to my remote one on GitHub. From my understanding it is best-practice to work off of a branch of the master repo.

So, using GitBash, I created an empty `.txt` file `branchfile.txt` to a new working branch `b1`.

However, when I switch back to my master branch, the newly created `.txt` file is there too.

This was not my expectation, and I wanted to know if this is normal. If not, how can I fix this?

Comment: The files that you see and work with in your work-area (your working tree) are not in Git, they are just copied in and out of the repository as needed. A *new* file you have created in your work-area is not in Git at all (unless a file of that name exists in some old commit, but was removed, that is). So as you change branches, Git copies the *other* files in and out, but this new one is just sitting there in your work-tree, as a file that Git doesn't touch. It is not in *any* branch.

Comment: Once you tell Git that the file should go into the *next* commit (using `git add`), and then make that next commit, *then* the file is in the latest commit on whichever branch—and now Git knows to *remove* the file if you switch to some other branch. I know there are duplicates for this question, I just haven't found them yet. :-)

Comment: Hmm, not the best duplicate, but: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15209217/1256452

Comment: The files would need to be committed to the branch in order to only appear on the branch then? 

And i've looked in many places to get clarification on this. I was following this walk-through to help clarify branches... and I hit a wall when i saw the new file in both the master and the new branch -- https://thenewstack.io/dont-mess-with-the-master-working-with-branches-in-git-and-github/

Answer (score 3):

Once a file is committed to a branch, and it hasn't been changed since the commit, switching to a branch without that file will make it disappear from the working directory.